# Is it possible to include OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureId in a Logical.AND Filter

Tags: filter, openlayers

I'm trying to construct a Logical.AND filter in OpenLayers that combines a FeatureID filter with a Comparison.EQUAL_TO filter.  The goal is to filter for a property among a set of features filtered by their fids.  Here's some example code:

```
        var compfltr= new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
            property: 'cat',
            value: 'restaurant'
        });

        var idfltr= new OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureId({
            fids: ['f09de70a-9629-4aac-afd2-00375d7e920f', '77d51ff0-6f85-4503-90ca-27d78e270ebd', '5d19df37-ed3b-4e06-8ca2-001b832713dc', '36841c4f-cfc9-4440-beb3-001dd7a9a754', '4ca129c9-62e4-41b8-8a49-00239612cd59']
        });

        var selfilter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND
        });
        selfilter.filters.push(compfltr)
        selfilter.filters.push(idfltr)

        var rule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
            filter: selfilter,
            symbolizer: { fillColor: "#7FCC7F", fillOpacity: 0.9, strokeColor: "#7FCC7F", strokeOpacity: 0.5, strokeWidth: 12, pointRadius: 10 }
        });
```

I have no problem constructing a Logical.AND filter with the other filter types, but when I include a FeatureId filter it fails.   Is it not possible to use a FeatureId filter in a Logical filter?

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers current version has a bit of inconsistency in their filter api.  Some filters get the feature itself and some get the attributes of the feature.  This breaks down because OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureID is the most filter that requires the feature and most of the API including OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison are passing the feature attributes around.

I actually wrote a solution to this and offered it to the OpenLayers community on Github.  Feel free.

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/1138

Comment: Thanks so much for confirming my suspicions!  I'll take a look at your solution.

Comment: Feel free to comment/add examples/what-have-ya to Github.  I like feedback.